# Javascript Sluggish player movement

Tags: javascript, canvas

**UPDATE**
changed it to the following and noticed speed improvements. The issue now is that the player will just slide without animating the frames.

```
    var animator, frames;
    animator = window.setInterval(function(){
    if(currentFrame == totalFrames){
        clearInterval(animator);
        currentFrame = 0;
        update();
        isMoving = 0;
        return;
    }
    xPosition += x;
    yPosition += y;
    frames = window.requestAnimationFrame(animator);
    currentFrame++;
    update();   

},frames);
```

Some of the issues I am currently facing are: the map edges code section is completely broken. I am just trying to make it so that the player cannot move beyond the canvas.width/canvas.height. Also, my player movement is very sluggish and unresponsive. I think it's because of the isMoving check I added. I want to be able to move much smoother. Right now the character takes so long to move that I feel as if I am lagging. Also, for some reason, sometimes it'll move more than one time. It is completely random when it happens. Any help would be appreciated

```
var playerSprite = new Image();
playerSprite.src = "male.png";

var playerWidth = 64;
var playerHeight = 64;
var currentFrame = 0;
var totalFrames = 8;

var moveDistance = 4; // move 4 pixels
var xPosition = 300;
var yPosition = 200;
var direction = 2; // south, options: 0 - 3

var isMoving = 0;

var canvas, context;
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
    canvas = document.getElementById('map');
    context = canvas.getContext('2d');
 })


function draw(){
    context.drawImage(playerSprite,currentFrame * playerWidth, direction*  playerHeight ,playerWidth,playerHeight,xPosition,yPosition,playerWidth,playerHeight);
}

function update()
{
    clearMap();
    draw();
}

function move(x, y){

    if(isMoving)return;
    isMoving = 1;

    if(x > 0) direction = 3;
    else if(x < 0) direction = 1;
    if(y > 0) direction = 2;
    else if(y < 0) direction = 0;

    //update direction no matter what, implemented 
    // in order for directions to update
    // when changing directions in map edges
    //update();

/*      Broken

    if(xPosition + playerWidth + x > canvas.width)return; //works
    else if(xPosition - x < 0)return; // player gets stuck

    if(yPosition + playerHeight + y > canvas.height)return; //works
    else if(yPosition - y < 0)return; // player gets stuck

    //xPosition += x;
    //yPosition += y;
*/
    //actual animation update
    var animator;
    animator = window.setInterval(function(){
        if(currentFrame == totalFrames){
            clearInterval(animator);
            currentFrame = 0;
            update();
            isMoving = 0;
            return;
        }
        xPosition += x;
        yPosition += y;
        currentFrame++;
        update();

    },1000/16);
}
function clearMap(){
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}

function keyPress(e)
{

    if(currentFrame == totalFrames){
        currentFrame = 0;
    }

    switch(e.keyCode){
        case 38: move(0, -moveDistance); break;
        case 40: move(0, +moveDistance); break;
        case 39: move(+moveDistance, 0); break;
        case 37: move(-moveDistance, 0); break;
    }

}

window.addEventListener("load", update, false);
window.addEventListener("keydown",keyPress);
```

Comment: instead of 1000/16 in the interval use `requestAnimationFrame`  you can find more details here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame

Comment: I've been researching that function since yesterday and I have no idea how to make proper use of it :/

Comment: Updated the code. Still have an issue, please take a look

Comment: You should not be using window.setInterval at all.

Comment: I just started using JavaScript and learned about canvases yesterday. What should I be using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Main points I changed:

- No use of `setInterval` anywhere. Instead we let the browser handle the FPS at a rate it can handle using `requestAnimationFrame`.
- **One central game loop** (`update()`). Before, you were doing a bunch of calculations and starting new background loops every time you press a key. That's bad. If someone were to mash the arrow keys, the browser would have to process 100+ `setInterval`s in the background.
- Instead of doing any calculation in the key events, we're just using a variable to keep track of which buttons are pressed. Then in the game loop, which happens each frame, we can move the player a few pixels if an arrow key is held.

Exercises for you:

- The animation is insanely fast because the player-frame is advanced every game-frame. Slow it down!
- If a faster computer runs at 60fps, the player will move 60 * 4 = 240 pixels every second. If a slower computer runs at 20fps, the player will only move 20 * 4 = 80 pixels every second. That's actually a huge difference. To make your game run consistently regardless of platform, **you should move the player more or less depending on how fast the game is running.** [Here's a good article](http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/fix-your-timestep/) to get you started. Also the [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) documentation will be helpful.

Here's the code:

```
var playerSprite = new Image();
playerSprite.src = "male.png";

var playerWidth = 64;
var playerHeight = 64;
var currentFrame = 0;
var totalFrames = 8;

var direction = 2; // south, options: 0 - 3
var moveDistance = 4; // move 4 pixels
var xPosition = 300;
var yPosition = 200;

var left = 0,
    right = 0,
    up = 0,
    down = 0;

var canvas, context;

window.addEventListener("keydown", keyPress);
window.addEventListener("keyup", keyRelease);
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
    canvas = document.getElementById('map');
    context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    // tells the browser to call update() as soon as it's ready
    // this prevents lockups, and also the browser regulates the FPS
    window.requestAnimationFrame(update);
});

function update() {
    // EVERYTHING game related happens in update (except listening for key events).
    // This keeps everything organized, and prevents any lag/slowdown issues

    // handles player movement and animation
    movePlayer();

    // handles all drawing
    draw();

    // lets the browser know we're ready to draw the next frame
    window.requestAnimationFrame(update);
}

function movePlayer() {
    if(left) {
        xPosition -= moveDistance;
        direction = 1;
    }
    if(right) {
        xPosition += moveDistance;
        direction = 3;
    }
    if(up) {
        yPosition -= moveDistance;
        direction = 0;
    }
    if(down) {
        yPosition += moveDistance;
        direction = 2;
    }

    // all this code happens every frame
    // in english: if we're moving, advance to the next frame
    if(left || right || up || down) {
        currentFrame ++;
        if(currentFrame == totalFrames) currentFrame = 0;
    }
}

function draw() {
    // clear the map
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    // draw the next frame
    context.drawImage(playerSprite, currentFrame * playerWidth, direction * playerHeight,
                                    playerWidth, playerHeight,
                                    xPosition, yPosition,
                                    playerWidth, playerHeight);
}

// keyPress and keyRelease ensure that the variables are
//  equal to 1 if pressed and 0 otherwise.
function keyPress(e)
{
    switch(e.keyCode){
        case 38: up = 1; break;
        case 40: down = 1; break;
        case 39: right = 1; break;
        case 37: left = 1; break;
    }
}

function keyRelease(e)
{
    switch(e.keyCode){
        case 38: up = 0; break;
        case 40: down = 0; break;
        case 39: right = 0; break;
        case 37: left = 0; break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, sir. Great answer! and yes, I will do my homework xD

Comment: So, hm. Admittedly,  I'm not sure what to do. I don't know the equivalent of integrate() and render() in JavaScript. I haven't been able to do anything after getting the delta time.

Comment: In the [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) documentation, it says that the callback function has an argument -- the number of milliseconds since the window opened. The callback would be your update function, so you could change `function update() {` to `function update(milliseconds) {`. You'll need another global variable to keep track of what `milliseconds` was the last frame, and subtract `milliseconds` from that to find out how long it's been since the last frame.

Comment: What I mean is, I figured that part out. I don't know how to get the animation to display at that speed though

Comment: Oh I see. Well one way to do it would be to have another global variable called `animationCounter` or something, and increment it by the delta time every frame. Then once it exceeds a certain amount (e.g. `1000 / 4 = 250` to have `4fps`) reset it to 0 and only *then* do `currentFrame++`.

Comment: Welp, apparently I don't know what I'm doing. I defined  `var lastTick = Date.now();`, changed `update()` to `function update(thisTick){` and tried to get the delta time by doing `var deltaTime = thisTick - lastTick;`
then I did `animationCounter += deltaTime;` and `lastTick = thisTick;`
and of course checking the animationCounter on my player movement function.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** Forgot to mention that I opted to include delta on my player's movement instead of on my update() redraws to prevent the whole game from running at 20 fps.

Forgot to post my revised and fully functional code. Thanks @Entity for helping me out <3. As you can see, I've begun to take more liberties and experimenting as well.

```
var fps = 20, fpsInterval = 1000/fps, now, then = Date.now(), delta;
var moving = {38:0, 40:0, 39:0, 37:0} // north, south, east, west

function move(direction, toggle){moving[direction] = toggle}
function keyDown(e){move(e.keyCode,1)}
function keyUp(e){move(e.keyCode,0)}

function playerMovement(){
    now = Date.now();
    delta = now - then;
    if(delta > fpsInterval){
        then = now - (delta % fpsInterval);
        // north = 38, south = 40, east = 39, west = 37
        // stop movement stall from opposite directions
        if(moving[38] && moving[40]){move(40,0)}
        if(moving[39] && moving[37]){move(37,0)}
        // flip order to change diagonal rendering mode
        if(moving[38]) {direction = 0; yPosition -= moveDistance};
        if(moving[40]) {direction = 2; yPosition += moveDistance};  
        if(moving[39]) {direction = 3; xPosition += moveDistance};
        if(moving[37]) {direction = 1; xPosition -= moveDistance};  

        if(moving[38] || moving[40] || moving[39] || moving[37]) currentFrame++;
        if(currentFrame == totalFrames) currentFrame = 0;
    }

}
```